# Find item in combined list

Tags: python, list

I want to combine list and do some tasks with its items. Then I want to know to which initial list belongs current item. How can I do it in less ugly way than now:

```
 combined_list = sorted(max_peaks_eph + min_peaks_eph) # number of lists is about 10
        for item in combined_list:
            #do some tasks....
            if something ...........
                if item in max_peaks_eph:
                    label = 'max_peaks_eph'
                elif item in min_peaks_eph:
                    label = 'min_peaks_eph'
                print (label)
```

Comment: why do you need to combine and sort the lists? is that a requirement for the tasks?

Comment: @PedroRodrigues, there are dates in these lists. They must be operated from old to new.

Comment: Shouldn't your ```elif``` just be an else?

Comment: you can combine the items in _item descriptors_ where you would include both the item, date, and the list it came from. do you need an example for that? or is that suficient?

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim, may be. I combine 10 lists. So I shortened my code before posting.

Comment: Do you have duplicate ones or all are different from other

Comment: @IgorK. check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#If you don't have duplicate ones then this will work better than yours

```py
 combined_list = A+B+C
 sorted_list = sort(combined_list)
 item = something # that you need to find
 index = combined_list(item)
 if index< len(A):
   print("Item in A")
 elif index < len(A) +len(B):
  print("Item in B")
 else:
  print("Item in C)
```

Why this method is efficient is we don't need to iterate each time to check the element in the list we can check with length of the list.